# Local notifications fire at 3 times a day on particulate time in react native

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

I am using push notifications but my requirement is that it will show push notification automatically at 4:00pm, 10:00am but I didn't found any good package for react native so if any body have experience with local notification share with me.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

u can try scheduled notifications for that.